# Apache HttpClient JSON Post

Tags: json, post, httpclient

I try to send directly a JSON string with HttpClient 4.4 in an application (SWT/JFace) :

```
    public String postJSON(String urlToRead,Object o) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String result="";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlToRead);
        postRequest.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //postRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //{"mail":"admin@localhost", "password":"xyz"}
        String jsonString=gson.toJson(o);
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(jsonString);
        params.setContentType("application/json");
        params.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        postRequest.setEntity(params);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
    }finally {
        httpClient.close();;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I try to get the response from the server (Apache/PHP) with `$POST`

the correct content of `$POST` should be :

```
array("mail"=>"admin@localhost","password"=>"xyz")
```

When I use `content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`$POST` content is :

```
array( "{"mail":"admin@localhost","password":"xyz"}"=> )
```

When I use `content-type : application/json`

`$POST` is empty : array()

Is there a way to post the JSON string with HttpClient or should I use an `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` and add each member of my object in the entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the "NameValuePair" solution (not in the comments, the answer is too long), but I thought StringEntity was able to understand the JSON see [How to POST JSON request using Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059278/how-to-post-json-request-using-apache-httpclient-3-1) and there: [HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)

```
public String postJSON(String urlToRead,Object o) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String result="";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlToRead);
        postRequest.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //{"mail":"admin@localhost", "password":"xyz"}    
        JsonElement elm= gson.toJsonTree(o);
        JsonObject jsonObj=elm.getAsJsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry:jsonObj.entrySet()){
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getAsString()));
        }
         postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
    }finally {
        httpClient.close();;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way, the content of $POST is correct : `array("mail"=>"admin@localhost","password"=>"xyz")`