# How to send JSON data as body in POST request through HttpClient

Tags: mysql, json, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've a requirement. I have a working POST call `("http://localhost:8080/POSTAPI/table/testmaster/create")`. I sent `JSON` data through postman and details got inserted into MySQL database. Now i'm trying to send the `json` data through `apache httpcleint`. but, it failed to insert into `mysql` database.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/POSTAPI/table/testmaster/create");
    JSONObject testmaster = new JSONObject();
    testmaster.put("testRunId", testRunId);
    testmaster.put("testClassName", className);
    testmaster.put("testMethod", methodName);
    testmaster.put("createdBy", "leela");
    testmaster.put("createdDate", startDate);
    testmaster.put("lastUpdatedBy", "raghu");
    testmaster.put("lastUpdatedDate", endDate);
    testmaster.put("attribute1", "methodName");
    testmaster.put("attribute1Value",methodName );
    testmaster.put("attribute2", "result");
    testmaster.put("attribute2Value", successResult);
    testmaster.put("attribute3", "Test Suite");
    testmaster.put("attribute3Value", suiteName);
    testmaster.put("attribute4", "test group");
    testmaster.put("attribute4Value", TestGroup);
    testmaster.put("attribute5", "dataprovider");
    testmaster.put("attribute5Value", dataProvider);

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(testmaster.toString());
    post.setEntity(stringEntity);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Status: "+response.getStatusLine());
```

This is what i tried. if anybody have any idea of post operation through httpclient or any other alternative please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON request using Apache HttpClient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059278/how-to-post-json-request-using-apache-httpclient)

Comment: That didn't work actually.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
private class postJsonData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String responseString = null;

    private postJsonData() {
        super();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        this.dialog.setTitle("Please wait.");            
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Boolean result=false;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.2/android/jsonpost.php");

        try {
            JSONObject testmaster = new JSONObject();

            try {
                testmaster.put("testRunId", "1");
                testmaster.put("testClassName", "className");
                testmaster.put("testMethod", "methodName");
                testmaster.put("createdBy", "leela");
                testmaster.put("createdDate", "startDate");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_string", testmaster.toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                result = false;

            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
                result = false;
            }

        } catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ClientProtocolException : " + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            result = false;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "IOException : " + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Response from Server: " + responseString ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        if (success){

        }else{

        }

        super.onPostExecute(success);
    }

}
```

Here is my php code which accepts the json string and decode into array.

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['json_string'])) {
    echo "Empty json data"; 
    exit;
}else{
    $json_string = $_POST['json_string'];
}

$params = array();
$params = json_decode($json_string,true);
//echo $params['testClassName'];

var_dump($params);
?>
```